# Python tkinter how to get text from button I clicked on

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code like this (just part of a code). I need when someone click on the button that is in list named buttonList then it gets buttons text.
This is code how I make render of those buttons. Its normally in class I put only the main part of code here.
So how can I get buttons text on click on him ?

```
def obsahOkna(self):

    #vykresleni
    radek = 0
    bunka = 0
    for i in range(100):
        btn = Button(self.okno, text=seznamTextu[i], width="5", height="2", bg="black", command=self.getText)
        btn.grid(row=radek, column=bunka)

        bunka += 1
        if bunka == 10 :
            bunka = 0
            radek +=1

def getText(self, udalost):
    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem. Also please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Comment: What is bad on my question exactly? I added just a few code and described what I want

Comment: Well first off you don't show that you are working in a class and that change make a difference. I assume you are because your use of self in the method but still should be clear to the reader. You really don't want to have assumptions made when having a question answered.

Comment: Also if you don't provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then no one can test your code as is. So they have to make even more assumptions as to what you are doing with it in the first place.

Comment: Whole code is not need i just need way to get buttons text nothing else

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way to edit the button after it has been created as well as getting the text from the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here is an example using a class to perform what I think it is you are asking.

You want to use lambda in your command and assign the value of text to a variable. Then you pass that variable to the `getTest(self, text)` method to be able to print your button.

From your comment

> Whole code is not need i just need way to get buttons text nothing else

I have created a bit of code to illustrate what you are wanting.

EDIT: I have added code that will allow you to change the configs of the button as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

# created this variable in order to test your code.
seznamTextu = ["1st Button", "2nd Button", "3rd Button", "4th Button", "5th Button"]

class MyButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.obsahOkna()
    def obsahOkna(self):

        radek = 0
        bunka = 0
        for i in range(5):
            btn = tk.Button(self.parent, text=seznamTextu[i])
            btn.config(command= lambda t=seznamTextu[i], btn = btn: self.getText(t, btn))
            # in order for this to work you need to add the command in the config after the button is created.
            # in the lambda you need to create the variables to be passed then pass them to the function you want.
            btn.grid(row=radek, column=bunka)

            bunka += 1
            if bunka == 2 : # changed this variable to make it easier to test code.
                bunka = 0
                radek +=1

    def getText(self, text, btn):
        btn.configure(background = 'black', foreground = "white")
        print("successfully called getText")
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myApp = MyButton(root)


    root.mainloop()
```

Here is the result of running the program and pressing a couple buttons.

[image]